# What is the dimension (or units) of a CDF and PDF?

Tags: probability, random-variable, density-function, cumulative-distribution-function

Given a continuous random variable $X$, what are the units of the PDF and CDF of $X$?

Comment: The PDF question is answered at http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/4220/a-probability-distribution-value-exceeding-1-is-ok/4223#4223.  The CDF question is the easy one, because a CDF by definition is a *probability*.

Comment: PDF:  It got added at the last minute to the question.
CDF:  That's the conclusion I reached, but something was giving me some doubt about it.  Thanks!

Comment: You can see what a cdf measures right in the definition of the cdf: $F_X(x) = P(X\leq x)$. "$P$" stands for probability.

Comment: Yeah, that's a much more straightforward way of dealing with it.

Comment: To answer the PDf portion of the question, can I ask if you are familiar with calculus?